# Validation of HTTP Header with Javax.ws

Tags: java, web-services, http-headers

I am a little bit frustrated. I do not know how I can validate the http header. So let me give you a little bit of background:
I have an android app. The android app is calling my web service and the web service is handling the connection with the database. 
I am sending a token in the header of my app to the web service. In addition to that I am sending the data in a JSON format. So for instance my app will send something like that

Header
token: xyz

{"username":"abc","postMessage":"hello world"}

In the webservice I want to validate the token. So I created this method `

```
public String headerInfo(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders){
    String token = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("token").get(0);

    return cacheControl.toString(); }
```

In my other method I am calling this method, but of I am not able to add the right parameters here, so I am receiving NULL as a response. 
My method looks (for testing purpose) like that:

```
@GET
@Path("/validate")
public Response validation(String json){
//... get username and post from the json object, for testing I added the key token as well...//
String token = jsonObj.getString("token");
String headerToken = headerInfo();
//...compare token and headerToken...//

return Response... }
```

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

it was pretty easy in the end. Maybe it will help someone.
I just needed to add the HeaderParam in my method and I could access it.
 @HeaderParam("content-type") String ct